# error while inserting date in my table using sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle

i created the table with the below schema

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 FLIGHT_NUMBER                                      VARCHAR2(255)
 LEGNUMBER                                          NUMBER(38)
 DAY                                                DATE
 SEATNUMBER                                NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 CUSTOMERNAME                                       VARCHAR2(255)
 CUSTOMER_PHONE                                     NUMBER(38)
```

when i tried to insert the value

```
 insert into table seat_registration
  2  values('11',1,2017/10/10,10,'joshua',1100);
```

it shows

> ERROR at line 2:
>   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: what is your table name

Comment: i changed my error please resolve my issue and solve it

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: While I realise it makes little difference to the underlying table you should really choose column lengths that are realistic. Just picking some random defaults tells nothing about your data to a developer who wants to maintain your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap dates in single quotes.  I would recommend using standard formats with the `date` keyword:

```
insert into seat_registration
    values ('11', 1, date '2017-10-10', 10, 'joshua', 1100);
```

I would also recommend listing the columns:

```
insert into seat_registration(flight_number, leg_number, day, seat_number, customer_name, customer_phone)
    values ('11', 1, date '2017-10-10', 10, 'joshua', 1100);
```

Comment: i changed my error please check it resolve my issue now

Comment: How can insert  date in sql devloper

Comment: @joshua: that is explained in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the query for insertion.

```
    insert into seat_registration(flight_number, leg_number, day, seat_number, customer_name, customer_phone)
values ('11', '1', '2017-10-10', '10', 'joshua', 1100);
```

Answer (score 0):

date always write in '' quote in query and remove `table` keyword from query

```
insert into seat_registration values('11',1,'2017/10/10',10,'joshua',1100);
```

write date in `'2017/10/10'` instead of this `2017/10/10`